# Show $f(rx) = [f(x)]^r$ where $r\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Consider the function $f$ with the following properties:

$$(1) \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) =1,$$ 
$$(2) f(x+y)=f(x)f(y),$$
$$ -\infty<x,y<\infty.$$

Show that $f(rx)=[f(x)]^r$ where $r\in\mathbb{Q}$. Here's what I have so far.

Since $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ that implies that $r=\frac{p}{q}$ such that $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then we have that $f(rx)=f(\frac{p}{q}x) =f(\frac{x}{q}+\frac{x}{q}+...+\frac{x}{q}) = f(\frac{x}{q})f(\frac{x}{q})...f(\frac{x}{q}) = [f(\frac{x}{q})]^p.$ This is where i'm stuck. I'm not sure where to go from here given what I have.

Edit 1: Would it be possible to talk about $\frac{x}{q}$ in terms of $q^{-1}x$? I tried going through it this way but that seemed a bit of a stretch given the assumptions made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally we have:
$$
f(x)=f\left(\frac{x}{q}+\frac{x}{q}+\dots+\frac{x}{q}\right)=\left(f\left(\frac{x}{q}\right)\right)^q\iff \left(f(x)\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}=f\left(\frac{x}{q}\right)
$$
This should solve it.

Comment: Ah! I see now! Haha, have you done this exercise before or did that just come to mind immediately?

Comment: No, I already did it that way with a similar function :)

Answer (score 0):

$$[f(x)]^{p/q}=[f(\frac qqx)]^{p/q}=[f(\frac1qx)]^{qp/q}=[f(\frac1qx)]^p=f(\frac pqx).$$

Comment: I'm not sure how you got that implication from the LHS.

Comment: Take the $q^{th}$ root, just like in user109899's solution.

Comment: Thanks! Both answers helped!

Comment: I made it a little simpler.

Comment: Thank you for that. Both answers helped me find the missing link.